# 'undefined local variable or method' with render partial rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to render a modal form and be able to render it on differents places; hence I want to be able to change the order_id that is required to create a new feedback on server side (I use AJAX).

However, my render partial does not work. I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `user_order_id' for #<#<Class:0x007fec6be26af8>:0x007fec6bf1b2d8>
```

any Idea ?

index.html.erb

```
[...]

<%= render partial: 'feedback_modal', locals: {user_order_id: @user_last_order} %>

[...]
```

_feedback_modal.html.erb

```
   <%= simple_form_for(@review, method: :post, url: review_path(current_user.id, user_order_id), remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :rating, collection: [1,2,3,4,5], prompt: "Rate this meal", class: "col-sm-3" %>
      <%= f.label :comment, "Your comments" %>
      <%= f.text_area :comment, class: "commentaire" %>
      <%= f.button :submit ,"Send Feedback", class: "btn" %>
    <% end %>
```

controller:

```
[...]

    @user_last_oder = Order.where(user_id: current_user.id, status: nil).last.id

[...]
```

Comment: Can you check value using <% user_order_id ||= local_assigns[:user_order_id] %> in your _feedback_modal.html.erb ?

Comment: @sam Yes, It gives 'nil'

Comment: So first you should check value of @user_last_order from index page. What you pass from index that will you get in partial so you should check it first the instance variable value.

Comment: @sam thank you for your help. I already did, It actually gives the right value (like '5', for example). So I really do not see where the problem is.

Comment: So you mean, on index page it give 5 for @user_order_id ?

Comment: nop sorry my mistake it was a typo; it gives 5 (which is what i want) for `@user_last_order`, but gives nil for `user_order_id` , `local_assigns[:user_order_id]`, or `@user_order_id`

Comment: Please debug properly value from controller and tell me which you get.

Comment: The value from the controller is right. There is something wrong with the render partial. I should get '5' when I use user_order_id, but it gives nil.

Comment: Any hidden chars in calling the partial or form declaration? :D

Comment: @JulesCorb You have a typo in your controller, at least in the version you posted above: `@user_last_oder` vs `@user_last_order`

Comment: @GoGoCarl, @ Andres Ehrenpreis, thank you for your help ! It was probably a typo problem indeed. I actually made a few changes during the afternoon and it is now working.